# Converting constructor with multiple arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, type-conversion

In C++11, a constructor without `explicit` keyword can be used to convert a list of arguments implicitly to its class. For example:

```
class Date{
private:
  int d, m, y;
public:
  Date(int _d, int _m=0, int _y=0) : m(_m), d(_d), y(_y) {}
  friend bool operator==(const Date &x, const Date &y) {return  x.d==y.d;}
};

int main()
{
  Date x = {1,2,3}; // no error; using converting constructor
  x == 1; // no error; converting constructor turns int into Date object
  x == {1,2,3}; // error
}
```

For `x == {1,2,3}`, I got the following error:

```
explicit.cc:16:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
       x=={1,2,3};
          ^
```

I am wondering why converting constructor doesn't convert list `{1,2,3}` to `Date` object? Especially since `x == 1` does not result in an error, why does `x == {1,2,3}`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might be especially surprised that:

```
x = {1, 2, 3};            // ok
x == {1, 2, 3};           // error
operator==(x, {1, 2, 3}); // ok
```

This is because there are just specific places where a *braced-init-list* (basically, a comma-delimited list of stuff between `{}s`) is allowed to go in the language. It can go on the right-hand side of `=` because the rules say it can. It can be used as an argument in a function call expression because the rules say it can. But it cannot be used on either side of the comparison operators because the rules don't allow for it.

I do not know if there is a fundamental reason behind this beyond there probably not being a strong need for it.

Comment: I would add that a *braced-init-list* is not an *expression*, so it can only be used in a limited set of contexts where *expression*s are allowed.

Comment: @Brian Until for some reason `auto` deduced it to be an `initializer_list`. Ah the joys of C++.

Comment: IIRC, there are parsing issues, especially if the braced-init-list is the left operand.

Answer (score 6):

To complete Barry's answere, I made a list of all the statements or expressions where a `brace-init-list` can appear:

- function call : `func({/*...*/},arg2)`
- subscripting: `obj[{/*...*/}]`;
- explicit type conversion: `type{/*...*/}`
- new expression: `new type{/*...*/}`
- assignment and compound assignments: `a = {/*...*/}; b += {/*...*/};...`
- in the condition of a conditional statement `while (atype i={/*.../*})`
- for-range-initializer `for(auto it:{/*...*/})`
- return statement: `return {/*.../*}` (not if the return type is deduced)
- initializer: `atype a{/*...*}; atype b={/*.../*};` or including member initializer: `a_memb{/*.../*}`
- default argument `void f(atype a={/*.../*})`

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering why converting constructor doesn't convert list `{1,2,3}` to `Date` object?

Because it's not a "converting constructor". It is merely "a constructor".

List initialization (the thing that happens when you use a braced-init-list) is used for initializing an object from a list of values, as one might expect from the name. `x = {1, 2, 3};` is not initializing an object. `x` is an object that has already been initialized.

As such, braced-init-lists cannot be directly applied to an existing object; they can only be applied to an object that is being initialized. What you want to do is use the list to initialize a `Date` and then copy that `Date` into the existing `x` object. That's spelled `x = Date{1, 2, 3};`.

A "converting constructor" is a constructor which performs implicit conversions. An implicit conversion converts from an object of one type to an object of another type. List initialization is not, and never has been, a *conversion* operation. `Date x = {1, 2, 3};` does not convert a list into a `Date`; it initializes a `Date` with a list, using the rules of copy-list-initialization.